# I want to run aggregate query which also has find function in it?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am running an aggregate query in Mongodb which is

```
db.Data_Urls.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$Urls", Done:{$sum:1}}}])
```

so the result will be like

```
{ 
    "_id" : "hassan", 
    "Done" : NumberInt(1)
},    
{ 
    "_id" : "ahmed", 
    "Done" : NumberInt(3)
},    
{ 
    "_id" : "naveed", 
    "Done" : NumberInt(1)
},    
{ 
    "_id" : "ali", 
    "Done" : NumberInt(1)
},    
{ 
    "_id" : "haroon", 
    "Done" : NumberInt(2)
}
```

I want to filter the `Done` value also in the same query to only get `Done` values which has value 1?

Comment: Use **[$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)** after group

Comment: Why was this tagged MySQL? It looks like only MongoDB. Is there something missing from the question relating to the other database?

Comment: @Yogesh: Can you write query as i am novice to mongodb.

Comment: @Yogesh: Done thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Data_Urls.aggregate([
     {$group : {_id : "$Urls", Done:{$sum:1}}},
     {$match : { Done: 1 }}
])
```